# Documenting Django using UML

Tags: django, uml

Hello Stack Overflow Community

I'm trying to document my project and I have doubled on how to translate Django Views into UML Class Diagrams.

I have to mention that I'm not using class views, just normal views.

Can you please tell me if this is ok? Do I need to let know the reader what I'm trying to achieve or it is clear what the diagram says?

Many thanks in advance for your feedback

This is the code

```
def index_crypto(request):

    import requests
    import json

    #Api Call
    url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=1'
    headers = {'Accepts': 'application/json','X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY':'xxxxxxxxxx',}
    params = {'convert' :'USD'}
    api_request = requests.get(url, headers= headers,params= params) #Request Object

    try:
        data = json.loads(api_request.content) #JSON file containing data.

    except Exception as e:

            data = "Error...."
            print(e)

    api_assets= [] 

    for i in data["data"]:
        api_assets.append(i)

    return render(request,'index_crypto.html',{'api_assets': api_assets})
```

[image: This is the UML Class Diagram I have came up with:]

Answer (score 0):

By defining *index_crypto* as an operation in a class you would be fully compatible with UML.

Because *url, headers*  and *params* have a constant value and are only visible in *index_crypto* you can declare them as *read-only* (*{readOnly}*) *static* attribute (the name is underlined) with the visibility *private* rather than *public*

For *api_request* (*Request* in your diagram ?) it is not clear to use an attribute, it is a pure local working variable as we have in operations, better to remove it for me.

If I am not wrong *index_crypto* returns a *HttpResponse*

Comment: @caff_91 a read-only property is indicated with *{readOnly}* after the type, I was wrong to say there is no special notation

Comment: Thanks! I was just checking that and indeed {readOnly} goes there. Thank for the clarification.